# Where can I find types for react-router-dom Location, History and Match?

Tags: typescript, react-router, react-router-v4

When I use `withRouter` from `react-router-dom` v4.3.2, it passes three props to the component, `history`, `match` and `location`. Where can I find the type definition for these three objects for TypeScript?

I have checked this link https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/react-router/v3/lib but it doesn't have version 4. In addition, the type defined there doesn't include `History location and match`.

Comment: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/react-router/v3/lib

Comment: the repos doesn't have version 4.

Comment: Looks like they moved to https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/react-router-dom, although weirdly v5 is back over at `@types/react-router`. Anyway, the point is you can just look at DT for whichever `@types` package you're using.

Comment: How can I import the type from this package? I have tried `import { History } from @types/node' but it doesn't work

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have checked the code `https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react-router-dom/index.d.ts` but it doesn't have any types for `history`, `match` and `location.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```js
import { History, Location } from 'history';
import {match} from 'react-router';
```

You can check out `@types/react-router`. There you can see all the types defined and imported from `@types/history`.

Comment: Thanks. How about the other two, `match` and `location`?